# Translation-Question:

Tags: translation

I have a translation question:
Below sentences are from a longer text about doctors, their patients and those "declaration of consent" forms that patients often have to sign to receive treatment.

身近な家族や友人、知人の経験から自分の病気に対する取り組みを決める患者も非常に多い。患者本位の診療をしたいと、自分の理想とする医療の実現を目指して一生懸命になってインフォームドコンセントを得ようとしながら挫折する若い医師は珍しくない。

I am not quite sure if I understand the second sentence correctly. The first one is clear I think i.e. patients (tend to) ask their friends etc. for laymen-diagnosis and treatments.

Does the 2nd mean smth like "Despite of those declaration of consents many doctors are frustrated about patients trying to push through their self-diagnosis"?
Thx for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

> 「患者本位の診療をしたい」と(考えて）、自分の理想とする医療の実現を目指して、一生懸命になってインフォームドコンセントを得ようとしながら、挫折する若い医師は珍しくない。

I guess the above can be roughly translated into something like

> It is not unusual to see young MDs getting frustrated by failing to practise informed consent as a form of patient-oriented treatment in their pursuit of ideal medication.

Caveat: the above translation is not verbatim.

Comment: Yes, I think this helps, thanks. 

So, "pleasing everybody" becomes more and more a frustrating challenge to MDs as the patients often have a certain expectation (from friends, family, etc) of what their treatment should be. MDs are struggling to meet these expectations but still provide the treatment the patient needs and at the same time enables him to understand what a certain treatment mean (i.e. consequences if something goes wrong)?

Thx, this is a really hard sentences.

Comment: @toobee: You are welcome. I understand the situation of medical profession becomes harder and harder. By the way, I believe the sentence is hard because it is unnecessarily intricate. The authour should have written it in plain Japanese. I sincerely hope someone should establish the Japanese version of this -> plainenglish.co.uk .